# Parallel Structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I read the following script in a TOEIC Speaking book:

“Hi, Mohammed. This is Sam.
I just got your voicemail about the printing job.
I would rather go with the original printer. **Maybe you can ask them to print twenty copies first and make sure they deliver them on time**, before you have a meeting with a client, and then they can finish up the rest of the copies later… after you have a meeting.”

I think the bold-faced sentence can be analyzed into the following:

1. You can ask them to print twenty copies first and (you can ask them to) make sure they deliver them on time.
2. You can ask them to print twenty copies first and (you can) make sure they deliver them on time.

Which one do you think is correct? #1? #2?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Closely related: [Ambiguous relative clause](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158116/ambiguous-relative-clause).

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed is definitely the one that has to make sure they deliver them on time.
If the writer meant that the printers have to make sure themselves that they deliver on time, he/she would probably have said :

"Maybe you can ask them to print twenty copies first and **to** make sure they deliver them on time."

It is a bit heavier but removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and simple explanation! I like it! ^^

Comment: But it's inconsistent. It's unacceptable to follow 'Mohammed is definitely the one that has to make sure they deliver them on time.' with '[Version B] removes any ambiguity.'

Comment: Well i don't have any doubt in the matter, but someone else might (hence the OP's question). Whatever the case is, [version B] does remove any ambiguity one might have.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Sam is asking Mohammed to make sure that the printer delivers them on time, for example by checking with the printer a couple of times that they are on target to deliver them on time.

Comment: 'I believe' probably indicates a level of doubt.

Comment: Well, it's always hard to be certain about what's meant by some random bit of text.

Comment: I think the opposite from Max. But it is ambiguous as written. In speech, the phrasing and tone of voice would probably have clarified it.

Comment: If you're leaving it up to the printer to make sure it's on time, what would you do?  When you make the booking, would you say "Oh, and could you deliver it on time please?"  The printer would say "Yes, of course!", possibly slightly insulted that you'd asked.  And then (in my experience) they might deliver it late, for a variety of reasons, such as disorganisation and general incompetence (I've dealt with printers).  If it's very important to Sam that the materials are delivered on time, then Mohammed needs to take extra steps to make sure it happens.

Comment: See also delivering something with obvious printing flaws, or that simply isn't what you asked for, or delivering it to the wrong address. etc.

Comment: What I'm saying is that (as Colin adds) as written, there is an ambiguity. Your reading is _probably_ the intended one, but that's a pragmatic deduction. This sort of question has been addressed (and pointed out as an example of ambiguity) on ELU before, but I'm not spending an hour trying to find the original.

Comment: Oh yeah, i'm definitely not sure that my interpretation is correct - that's why I said "I believe...".   My confidence in my guess is actually slipping, i'm probably only 60/40 now.

Comment: Then it should not be given as an 'answer' on ELU. // The question _has_ been addressed before; I'm impressed with the best (thb's) answer there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry, i think i've misunderstood the rules of the site.  Can you please post a link to the rule which says "Don't answer unless you're 100% stake-your-life-on-it sure about something?".  I mean that genuinely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth all fair points.  However, in a question with genuinely ambiguous text such as this I don't believe it's possible to provide a definiive answer, backed by research.  Also the questioner asked "Which one do you think is correct?", meaning they want an opinion.  That arguably pushes the question itself into "bad question" territory, for inviting opinion-based answers.  So, one is left with the choice of giving an opinion-based answer, or voting to close the question.  I chose to answer.

Comment: There is a quote on [Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/what-is-the-difference-between-opinion-and-fact): 'We are assured that on EL&U questions must not be posted whose answers can only be opinion-based. And - if your answer isn't factual, it'll be closed immediately.' / Matt Gutting has stated elsewhere: 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references'. / And Sven Yargs has posted: 'Your answer seems to be heavily weighted toward personal opinion as opposed to ...

Comment: objective analysis—but this site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just opinion. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do with regard to usage.' (He's being especially gentle; the fact is that opinions-as-answers can be and sadly often are unhelpful or downright misleading. And from your switch from 'I believe that Sam is asking Mohammed ... 'to 'My confidence in my guess is... slipping: I'm probably only 60/40 now', you don't see the answer as great.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought my answer might be helpful to the questioner.  We clearly both love an argument and thus run the risk of spending hours arguing about whether or not my answer was worthwhile.  I think it's best if you (and indeed others) simply downvote answers that you think are of poor quality.